# AngularJS to Angular - Issues integrating with a CMS

Tags: angular, webpack

I am trying to convert an AngularJS project to Angular. The problem I have is replicating the current usage. So, I have a controller, something like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('MySite')
        .controller('ContentController', ContentController);

    function ContentController($timeout) {
         ...
```

And a html file for example:

```
<div class="content-wrapper section" data-ng-controller="ContentController as content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h2>H2 Subheading</h2>
                ...
```

Then, I have another js file:

```
importClass(com.somesite.Utils); // 

try {

    var body = Utils.process(dbStatement, publishCache, section, content, language, isPreview, '<custom type="content" name="Content" output="normal" modifiers="" />');

    var html = '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10"><h2>Subheading</h2></div>';

    html = html.replace('<h2>H2 Subheading</h2>', body);

    document.write(html);

} catch (err) {
    document.write(err);
}
```

The html and controller are added as you see (separate files) to a content management system and are linked to a 'content type'. When a user creates a new page in the CMS they can choose to build it using a number of different content types e.g. 'text only', 'image and text'. For each, an associated controller and html file are used.

In this case, when the user inputs text into the content item and then saves the change, the additional js file is called upon to replace the contents of the html file with what they have typed (via the CMS - the importClass and string replace on the body variable).

The only way I can currently separate a component in Angular is through a lazy loaded module. I am currently compiling with the Angular CLI i.e. ng build. I encounter a couple of problems:

1. Lazy loaded modules work by having defined routes, but in this case it would not work. The page the user is creating will have its own URI, but the component is just providing functionality for a 'content type'.

For example,

```
{ path: 'content-text-only', loadChildren: () => import('./content-text-only/content-text-only.module').then(m => m.ContentTextOnlyModule) },
```

The website will never have a page [www.website.com/content-content](http://www.website.com/content-content). It will have a page such as [www.website.com/some-page](http://www.website.com/some-page) which is made up of different content types.

2. How do I possibly update the html in a similar fashion when the angular application is compiled already.
3. If it is possible to separate the HTML from the component on compile that would be something I would be interested in, but it may not be necessary if the above can be addressed.

Comment: which angular are you trying to use ?

Comment: Angular 12. I have converted the AngularJS code to Angular 12.